# lscpu Tells me I have 8 CPUs (Cores) yet there's 1 socket with 4 cores

Tags: cpu

I got information on my hardware with `lscpu` and it says that I have 8 CPUs (cores). Then it said that I have 2 threads per core, which makes sense, but then it said that I have 4 cores per socket, and I have one socket. How can I have one socket that contains 4 cores yet I have 8? Is `lscpu` messed up or something? Why is this happening?

It could be that since I'm kind of a noob at this and I just don't understand. Thanks in advance.

Ubuntu 20.04

Dell Inspiron 17 3000

Intel Core i7

Comment: "_I have 9 CPUs (cores)._" Is it 9? Or is it 8?

Comment: @FedKad sorry a typo...I edited

Comment: you have 8 hyper thread cores ... in a terminal issue  `htop` which will show usage of each core

Answer (score 1):

cpus (8) = sockets (1) * cores (4) * threads (2)

Processes that do heavy math should use 4 threads.  Things that don't do heavy math (especially if at least half of them are doing I/O) can use 8 threads effectively.

Definition of "heavy" at least partly depends on how many multiplies the code wants to do in parallel, but this depends on the cpu model and architecture, and how many ALUs it has per core.